# Does time in Norende pass for other players?

Tags: bravely-default

My sister and I are playing *Bravely Default* on my 3DS. A big concern for us is if time is passing in Norende for only the player who is loaded or all players of the game. Is time passing only for the player with the loaded game or does time in Norende pass for all players?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've checked, and time **in Norende** only passes for the loaded game, whether the 3DS is active or asleep doesn't matter (village time is separate from the game timer or overworld time).

Answer (score 2):

In-game time is not shared among players. However much time passes for you, however many day/night cycles you go through, will have no effect on your sister's game. It can be daytime for you and nighttime for her in-game because there is no inter-player interaction outside of sending moves, Streetpassing, sending Nemeses, and other related actions.